# Handling async model data in EmberJS 1.0.0

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, ember.js, models, legacy-code

I am using EmberJS v1.0.0-pre.4 for a project at work ... old yes ... but since its for work ... and I have problems upgrading (not sure if the company will want to also), I guess I have to find a workaround.

I just want to use load data for my model asynchronously ... I believe with latest version, I can return a promise for my model ...

```
App.XRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON(...);
    }
});
```

But with the old version, it appears this does not work ... so how should I handle async data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment, I'll gladly keep working with you on this, but it appears to work 1.0 pre 4

```
 App = Ember.Application.create();

 App.Router.map(function () {
     // put your routes here
 });

 App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(['red', 'yellow', 'blue']);
        }, 2000); 
      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Are you using some library? Where does Promise come from?

Comment: Promise is native in HTML5, http://caniuse.com/promises ;)  But it works essentially the same as RSVP promises or jquery promises.

Comment: Oh it "works" without error, problem is view is rendered even when promise has not been resolved.

Comment: Weird, mine totally blocks, if I up it to 20 seconds the page spins and waits for 20 seconds to load.  Can you try and reproduce in a jsbin?

Answer (score 1):

There is something with the jQuery promise-implementation that doesn't work that well with Ember, I can't for my life remember what it was now though..

There is however a great wrapper that you can use for this called [ic-ajax](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax). It supports the same syntax as `jQuery.ajax` but wraps it in a promise using the [RSVP-library](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.html) that Ember uses. It also only add about 4kb unminimized so it isn't going to make your project size skyrocket.

I've been using in two Ember-projects so far and now it's included with [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com) as well (I'm in no way affiliated with the ic-ajax project or it's developers, I just think it's great).

Comment: jquery doesn't respect the fail `then` use case properly, meaning it won't hit the failed callback.  In this example it should hit pink/purple: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/876/edit.  ic-ajax essentially copied what ember data did: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L602 which essentially wraps jquery's ajax call with rsvp like you said giving you something like this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qimudotu/1/edit.

Comment: Additionally they fixed another recursive self fulfilling issue here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L559

Comment: This isn't me recommending Ember Data at all, just explaining the issues that were worked around ;)